# Put Information form Content Script into popout.html- Chrome Extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I wrote a content script for a chrome extension that parses information from a website and displays them to the user. I can see this information if I console log it so I know the script is getting the information I want, but I don't know how to send that back to the popout I made.

So for example I have a line that pulls the header from a website the user is on

```
titlearea = document.getElementById("titlelarge").innerText;
```

However when I try to set the the title element in my popout.html file to titlearea nothing happens. Obviously the information isn't getting there. How do I transfer all the data I collect?

-Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in you content script, send the data you want to show to popout page with [sendMessage API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html)

then you can show the data：）